# DWR class.js file not generated

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, dwr

I am a newbie to DWR. I was trying to access a java class using DWR script.

I am using DWR with struts as web layer and internally spring for dependency injection.

My Web.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com  /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns  /javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_TAPE" version="3.0">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>  
      <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>debug</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

My dwr.xml is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE dwr PUBLIC
       "-//GetAhead Limited//DTD Direct Web Remoting 2.0//EN"  
        "http://getahead.org/dwr/dwr20.dtd">
    <dwr>
          <allow>
        <create creator="new" javascript="task">
               <param name="class" value="com.Task"/>
        </create> 
          </allow>
    </dwr>
```

In my JSp, I added below three lines:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src="<%=contextString %>/dwr/engine.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="<%=contextString %>/dwr/util.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/dwr/interface/task.js"></script>
```

and this is how I am trying to access "task" script:

```
    var count = task.getTaskCount();
    alert(count);
```

The method getTaskCount is a simple method that returns int value.

Now, in my above code, I am able to access engine.js and util.js files using 
/dwr/.

But when I try to access task.js file using url:
/dwr/interface/task.js, the script isn't generate and below error is generated on console:

```
    2014-04-23 18:48:55,896 ["http-bio-8444"-exec-9] WARN          org.directwebremoting.servlet.ExceptionHandler:67  - Unhandled Exception
    java.lang.SecurityException: No class by name: taskBL
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultCreatorManager.getCreator(DefaultCreatorManager.java:189)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.generateInterfaceScript(DefaultRemoter.java:158)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.InterfaceHandler.handle(InterfaceHandler.java:50)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doGet(DwrServlet.java:132)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use dwr.xml file (I have empty one). I use annotations (@RemoteProxy for example), but I am not sure if You are using javascript attribute properly (in Your dwr.xml file). I think it is not the identifier You use in Javascript to invoke remoted Java objects.

Try include js script like that (note the capitalized **T** letter):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="<c:url value='/dwr/interface/Task.js' />"></script>
```

url tag is from `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>` which works for me and I think its prettier.

Then method invocation in Javascript would look like that (again the capitalized **T** letter):

```
Task.getTaskCount();
```

Please have a look at my Web.xml. I use annotations so I needed init-param: classes. It tells dwr what classes will be remoted.

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>classes</param-name>
        <param-value>com.Task</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>crossDomainSessionSecurity</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```